# Need help presenting a view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uialertview, viewcontroller

I have a class that has an extension of `UIButton` that shows a `UIAlertview` under certain circumstance.

```
@interface CellButton : UIButton {}

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You Lose!"
                                                      message:@"Play Again?"
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"cancel", nil];
[alert show];
```

This works fine, but I need to present a view controller when user presses ok.But as you may know you cannot present a view controller with an extension of `UIButton`.

So I was wondering if I can put the code below in another viewcontroller and allow it to work with the `UIAlert` in `Cellbutton` class.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {     // and they clicked OK.
        GameController*myNewVC = [[GameController alloc] init];
        [self presentModalViewController:myNewVC animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: give the button subclass a protocol.

Comment: you shouldn't really do that kind of thing in a UIView subclass really, do it in a controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't do it inside the UIButton.

The target of clicking the UIButton should be a UIViewController. After that, show an alert view FROM the view controller, and the view controller will be the delegate of the UIButton. From their everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This would work as long as you have set the alert view delegate to the view controller you want to handle the presentation.

I would suggest moving all of the functionality to the view controller though, i.e. present and handle the alert view from the same view controller, this can be triggered from an event from the button. I think this makes the code more readable and it doesn't really make sense for a button to know about alert views

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a global variable (in appDelegate - and how to do it [HERE](http://derekneely.com/2009/11/iphone-development-global-variables/)) then ;
1 - set the variable 1 when user click button
2 - get the value from other viewcontroller's action
if the value is 1 then go ahead.